# Disable dropdown depending of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable dropdown if `prov` radio button is not selected. I only want to enable it if `prov` is selected.

I created a demo of it, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

**Html:**

```
<td colspan="4">
    <input type="radio" name="editList" id="prov"value="Prov">Prov
    <input type="radio" name="editList" id ="user"value="User">User
    <input type="radio" name="editList" id="suc "value="Suc">Suc
<select id="cuadrilla" class="form-control select2 select2-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="1 Year" selected="selected">1 Year</option>
<option value="2 Years">2 Years</option>
<option value="3 Years">3 Years</option>
</select>                  
</td>
```

**JS**

```
$('input:radio[name="editList"]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == prov) {
                $('#cuadrilla').attr('disabled', true);
            } else
                $('#cuadrilla').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSmVD/346/)

Comment: Consider using `prop('disabled', true)/prop('disabled', false)` instead of `attr/removedAttr`. It makes more sense logically. And, that way you can do it in one like `prop('disabled, $(this).val() === 'Prov')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in your code with your If/Else block. Also, you are referencing the ID "prov" of the radio button, instead of the value Proveedor

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input:radio[name="editList"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Proveedor") {
      $('#cuadrilla').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#cuadrilla').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
  
  $('input:radio[name="editList"]')[0].click();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="radio" name="editList" id="prov" value="Proveedor" />Proveedor
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="user" value="Usuario" />Usuario
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="suc " value="Sucursal" />Sucursal
<select id="cuadrilla" class="form-control select2 select2-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="1 Year" selected="selected">1 Year</option>
<option value="2 Years">2 Years</option>
<option value="3 Years">3 Years</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what about if I want to disable it at the start and enable it only when I clic "Proveedor", its like document.ready don´t works, I want to start it with disable option

Comment: trigger click()... `$('input:radio[name="editList"]').click(function() { }).click()`

Comment: Updated snippet to have it start with disabled option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes for 'Prov':

```
 $('input:radio[name="editList"]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Prov') {
                $('#cuadrilla').attr('disabled', true);
            } else
                $('#cuadrilla').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
```